# How to connect TFS in Visual Studio code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS code. So far it seems very nice and much lighter than VS.
How could I connect my existing TFS server to VS code (my TFS must stay on premises - company requirements).
I read that this can be done but so far I've seen only examples for Git or TFVC.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team

Comment: Git and TFVC are the two source control options in TFS. If you're not using Git, you're using TFVC. Does that answer the question?

Comment: I believe you must be using a _local_ workspace for TFS. At least, I haven't been able to get it working with server workspaces... This tripped me up at one point.

Answer (score 60):

Just as Daniel said "`Git and TFVC are the two source control options in TFS`". Fortunately both are supported for now in VS Code.

You need to install the [Azure Repos](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode) Extension for **Visual Studio Code**. 
The process of installing is pretty straight forward.

1. Search for **Azure Repos** in VS Code and select to install the one by Microsoft
2. Open **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings**
3. Add the following lines to your **user settings**

   If you have VS 2015 installed on your machine, your path to Team Foundation tool (tf.exe) may look like this:

   ```
   {
       "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
       "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
   }
   ```

   Or for VS 2017:

   ```
   {
       "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe",
       "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
   }
   ```
4. Open a local folder (repository), From **View** -> **Command Pallette** ..., type **team signin**
5. Provide **user name** --> **Enter** --> Provide **password** to connect to TFS.

Please refer to below links for more details:

- [Using Visual Studio Code & Team Foundation Version Control
  (TFVC)](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2017/05/29/using-vscode-and-tfvc/)
- [Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) Support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start)
- [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

Note that Server Workspaces are not supported:

> "TFVC support is limited to Local workspaces":

[image: on installing Azure extension, visual studio code warns you "It appears you are using a Server workspace. Currently, TFVC support is limited to Local workspaces"]

Comment: @user355289 Have you resolved the issue? Any update?

Comment: What if you don't have any version of visual studio installed? Am I just out of luck if I want to connect VS Code to TFS then?

Comment: @MichaelS.Miller you can download Visual Studio Community, which includes TF.exe, or TEE CLC standalone from the link supplied by Andy (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#tfvc-command-line-client).

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT when I click on team : signin I get this error "(team) No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.", what should I do?

Comment: It does not work with vs code 2017. i think needs to be updated

Comment: I got this extension and got the message about it not working with server workspaces.  So I found how to change it to local, but when I do that it gets stuck at "Compressing and downloading baselines..."  I can't find anything that helps with why that is happening or how to get around it.

Comment: This extension appears to be [deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md).

Comment: The Azure Repo extension has been unpublished from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace since 2020-11-06.

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I did want to throw some interjections. (I would have commented but not enough reputation points yet, so, here's a full answer).

This requires the latest version of [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Azure Repo Extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team), and [Git](https://git-scm.com/) to be installed.

Anyone looking to use the new VS Code (or using the preview like myself), when you go to the Settings (Still File -> Preferences -> Settings or CTRL+, ) you'll be looking under User Settings -> Extensions -> Azure Repos.

[image: Azure_Repo_Settings]

Then under Tfvc: **Location** you can paste the location of the executable.

[image: Location_Settings]

For 2017 it'll be

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe`

Or for 2019 (Preview)

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe`

After adding the location, I closed my VS Code (not sure if this was needed) and went my git repo to copy the git URL.

[image: Git_URL]

After that, went back into VS Code went to the Command Palette (View -> Command Palette or CTRL+Shift+P) typed `Git: Clone` pasted my repo:

[image: Git_Repo]

Selected the location for the repo to be stored. Next was an error that popped up. I proceeded to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnDNdm1WCIo) which walked me through clicking on the Team button with the exclamation mark on the bottom of your VS Code Screen

[image: Team_Button]

Then chose the new method of authentication

[image: New_Method]

Copy by using CTRL+C and then press enter. Your browser will launch a page where you'll enter the code you copied (CTRL+V).

[image: Enter_Code_Screen]

Click Continue

[image: Continue_Button]

Log in with your Microsoft Credentials and you should see a change on the bottom bar of VS Code.

[image: Bottom_Bar]

Cheers!

Comment: Be aware that Stack Overflow doesn't allow comments to be posted as answers. That said, this can easily stand on its own as an answer.

Comment: @CodeNeedsCofee , do we really need to install Microsoftvisualstudio also to connect TFS from vscode, if no how can i get `TF.exe` path

Comment: @sdandamud1 you shouldn't need Visual Studio to use TFS. But if you do not have Visual Studio, you do need Team Explorer. Current Download Link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=15
Blog Link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/
TF.exe Path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe`

Comment: thank you, it's working like charm with `teamExplorer`

Comment: The updated TF.exe path as following:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe

Comment: @CodeNeedsCoffee can you provide latest Teamexplorer down load lik, what ever you provide above it's old version

Comment: got the latest one download link:https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=16

Comment: @CodeNeedsCoffee do we need to do any thing in vscode to use TFS from vscode based on this update?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the extension cannot be found anymore using "Visual Studio Team Services". Instead, by following the link in [Using Visual Studio Code & Team Foundation Version Control](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2017/05/29/using-vscode-and-tfvc/) on "Get the TFVC plugin working in Visual Studio Code" you get to the [Azure Repos Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode) GitHub. There it is explained that you now have to look for "Team Azure Repos".

Also, please note, that with the new Settings editor in Visual Studio Code the additional slashes do not have to be added. The path to tf.exe for VS 2017 - if specified using the "user friendly" Settings editor - would be just

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
```

Comment: This particularly help me to find the correct TF.exe path on my Machine and I added the path in the setting. Now it's works fine! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're wondering why you can't find the extension in VS Code's marketplace in 2021, it's because this extension was deprecated and removed. More info can be found here:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/6bc90f0853086623486d0e527e9fe5a577370e9b/DEPRECATED.md

Answer (score 2):

first of all, install "Argutec Azure Repos" from the extension and reset your IDE,

second, from file preference> setting > user > Extensions > Asure Repos
set the location of  tf.exe also set restrict workspace true,
after that search proxy in search setting and
Change HTTP Proxy support from Override to OFF,

third from the top menu View > Command Palette, type "team login"
then set your TFS user and password

now you are connected to TFS :)

Comment: I came across that problem too and this exactly was the final solution. I first reinstalled the outdate Azure Repos Extension by Microsoft via vsix but Argutec Azure Repos is working fine also following these instructions (which I originally found at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68442 , see the answer Feb 14th 2019). I am using VS Code 1.63.2.