# How to connect to tfs from VSCode 1.17

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I have tried to connect to TFS on my VSCode 1.17.2 by installing Visual studio team services.

[image]

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Update your vscode?

Comment: What ever i have that is latest one

Comment: 1.17 isn't the latest...?

Comment: Seems like the environment issue, have you checked the issue on other machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test the latest VS Code [`Version 1.22.2`](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and everything works as expected.

There is a thread talking about the issue here : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/245

It seems an environment issue based on **BrianFarnhill**'s conclusion:

> So based on that I've come to the conclusion that the issue I have
>   here is nothing related to you guys or your extension, but something
>   to do with this environment for my customer and it impacting on all
>   extensions.

So, you can try to troubleshoot the issue based on the discussion in that thread.

If that still not work, you can download the latest VS Code [`Version 1.22.2`](https://code.visualstudio.com/), then configure it following the guide [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start), then check if it works for you.

You can also reference [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070466/7466674) in another thread to do that.