# VS Code integration with TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc, team-explorer

I'm now starting to use VS Code and I like this tool except for the fact it won't integrate with TFS.

I have looked all over the place for a solution that would be easy to use and didn't find anything good.

The solution of TFVC that offered here [How to connect TFS in Visual Studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056972/how-to-connect-tfs-in-visual-studio-code) is not what I'm looking for.

I need to have the source control explorer and to be able to right click on a file to check it in and out.

Any good solution out there?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT yes, It's helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Visual Studio Team Services Extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode) for Visual Studio Code is the **only** official solution for now.

Source control explorer is something integrated with visual studio, which do not included in visual studio code.

If you really need this feature, you could submit a [uservoice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM and Admin will kindly review your suggestion.

As a workaround, suggest you to use the **tf command** to do the check in option.

Answer (score 0):

1.on the Tools menu, click Connect to Team Foundation Server.

2.in the Connect to Team Foundation Server dialog box, select a Team Foundation Server from the drop-down list.

3.Under Team projects, select one or more team projects from the list. Team projects with a check mark next to them will display in Team Explorer.

4.click OK.

Team Explorer displays the team projects under the selected Team Foundation Server.