# Unable to connect TFS server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VS code. So how could I connect my existing TFS server to VS code. I am using own TFS server URL and Its shown **Bad Request(400) over the Team icon** after enter user name and password in VS code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect TFS in Visual Studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056972/how-to-connect-tfs-in-visual-studio-code)