# FailedRequest: Service Unavailable(503) for TFS on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tfs, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to integrate VSCode with TFS using [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070466/10360808).

I have installed the Azure Repos extension and in my settings.json folder, I have done the following:

```
{
    "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\TF.exe",
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
}
```

While trying to do the `team signin` portion through the command palette however, I'm prompted with this message:

> Provide the username for server (servername:8080)

I enter this and my password, but the connection fails. On the bottom of my VSCode window, I can see this error message when I hover my mouse over the "Team" text:

> Failed Request: Service Unavailable(503) - http://servername:8080/tfs/companyprojectcollection/_apis/tfvc/branches

I'm a bit confused. On Visual Studio 2019, to add a server I just had to add the url as http://servername:8080/tfs and login with my credentials, after which I was able to view the workspace/folder that was created for me.

1. Do I need to edit the initial server it requests me to log into as "http://servername:8080/tfs" instead of "servername:8080", and if so, how?
2. Why does the error say service unavailable with added folders like companyprojectcollection/_apis/tfvc/branches? How do I fix this?

I could use Visual Stuio 2019, but VSCode is my preferred editor.

EDIT: The error while hovering over the Team button. This is the same format in which I saw the 503 error earlier, except that said "Service Unavailable(503)"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Failed Request: Service Unavailable(503) - http://servername:8080/tfs/companyprojectcollection/_apis/tfvc/branches

From the error message, it seems that the linked URL has some issue. Generally, the URL to connect to the tfvc repo is like this:

`http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/tfvcrepo`

Here are the steps to link the TFVC repo in VS code:

Step1: Create a workspace and map the workspace to local machine in **Visual Studio 2019**.

[image]

Then the Tfvc Repo will be checked out in the path.

Step2: Open either the root folder or a sub-folder of the TFVC repository (workspace path in step1) in VS code.

[image]

Step3: Run the `team signin` command  and input the Username and Password. Then the VS code could connect with the TFVC repo.

[image]

In this process, there is no process of customizing the URL, it will automatically recognize the tfvc repo related to the workspace.

**Note**: the settings.json file is still required for TFVC repo. Your settings are correct.

For mode detailed information, you could refer to this [Guidance document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#open-a-local-tfvc-repository-folder).

Comment: According to the guidance document you've linked, when I open the local folder to which I have mapped my workspace on the source control explorer, I should see 'Team O' with an exclamation mark (or a 1?) in the circle at the bottom. However right after opening the folder I see 'Team Ox' (with the x inside the circle) and hovering my mouse over it shows the Failed Request message mentioned above. Not sure why. I added a tfvc.proxy line to my settings.json file and noticed that the error code changed from 'Service Unavailable(503)' to 'Service Unavailable(400)' . Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Does a 400 error display when you hover over the team button?  I couldn't reproduce it now. But you may try to create a new workspace and check out the repo again in Visual Studio 2019. Then you could open the new folder in vs code. Please check if it could work.

Comment: There was another existing workspace. I mapped it to a different local folder (Documents) and ran a get to pull the necessary code. When I open 'Documents/ProjectFolder' on VSCode, I get the 400 error when I hover over the team button. I've added a screenshot of the error in my original post since I cannot add images in comments

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot. Test with the steps several times, but I still couldn't get the similar URL. To confirm this issue, you could directly visit this URL:`http://servername:8080/tfs/companyprojectcollection/_apis/tfvc/branches` , you could check if this URL is available. If it is unavailable, I suggestion that you could reconnect the Repo in Visual Stuido 2019. Please also share the TFS version with us.

Comment: "ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved" along with "Unable to determine IP address from host name "vitblrtfs03"" and DNS server returned Name Error.

TFS version: 14

Comment: Thanks for testing.  This issue indeed relates with the URL.  The URL is invalid.   Test  with TFS 2015 (version 14) , generally the URL: `http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/tfvcrepo`. You can check the URL directly on the browser if they are the same. You can reconnect the tfvc repo in visual stuido 2019 and export to the new workspace